# Files get opened in wrong editing area

Tags: eclipse

my Eclipse Juno SR1 somehow got screwed up. It seems I have a new area, and if I interpret it correctly, it is called the "Shared Area" (only from a tooltip). I cannot get rid of it by conventional means (i.E. closing/hiding). All files I open now are opened in this shared area, not in the area my files were opened before. The area is distinct from the normal editing area in that it will not go to the same place (top right, under the menus).

The area has only maximize and minimize buttons. Maximizing it will maximize it over everything, this would be expected. Minimizing it actually hides it, but opening an existing file will bring it back as kind of a popup over the eclipse file list.

I do not seem to find how I activated this feature, and I cannot seem to find any activation instructions in the Eclipse help (the help looking for "shared" and "area" separately doesn't really help anyway).

I just want this feature/window/perspective to go away and let me open files like I used to. Any tips?

Edit: Maybe this area is not called "Shared area", this could be wrong. If not, it doesn't seem to have any name. It just forces all editors opening new files to open in it, and not in the area that they usually open in. The way I determined it was called "Shared area" is by minimizing it, then opening a file. It opens as kind of a popup (described above), and there's a menu bar attached with 2 icons, "Restore" and "Shared area", which is pre-selected.

This is the are "docked" to the right:
[image]

This is the area docked below:
[image]

The area is not dockable in the way that it docks to certain areas of Eclipse, but stretches (when dragged) over the whole Eclipse Window and even outside of it.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You should reset the perspective `Window` -> `Reset Perspective...`

Comment: I never noticed there was such a thing as reset perspective before, really useful in this case as there is no way to close it.

Comment: ...But then if I open a new file, this shared area is back again! <:/ How the bloody hell can I remove that shared area..? :) I can minimize it away or reset the perspective, but it's always there ready to occupy most of the pixels I assigned to my console at runtime.

Comment: Have you tried switching to one of the default perspectives in the top right?  (I.e. JAVA EE or JAVA) and then re-arranging the windows back to your liking?

Comment: I saw "reset perspective" in your answer. I remember right click on perspective mini icon top right and select "reset". It closed some editors but it worked for me. Now editors open in the middle again.

Comment: Thank you !! 1000x I could not find it for weeks now.

Answer (score 8):

The shared area is the default location to open files. The files remain open in the shared area across different perspectives such as Java and Debug so that you can switch between them while working on the same files. You'd generally drag a file outside the shared area to work on it without it appearing in other perspectives.

It's hard to position the shard area view by dragging it, but you can drag the surrounding views in place around it to get it where you want.

Comment: This is GOLD, thank you so much! I did not realize the problem-pane I was dealing with was a special "master"-pane, I just thought it was a standard pane and was wanting to close it; once your comment made me realize what I was dealing with, it was easy to close the other pane I wanted to be my master-pane and then just move the other panes around the actual master-pane. 2 thumbs up!

Comment: "you can drag the surrounding views in place around it to get it where you want."
So simple I hadn't thought of it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I click on the bottom corner of the offending tile and dragged in till it closed!  The "reset perspective" did not work for me but the draggin to a smaller size as if it were a picture did. Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot drag part corners here, I can only drag-up the lower part till the offending one is thiner, but not closed at all.. ?

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works out for you, simply go to window -> new Window. Opens up a fresh copy of eclipse with everything loaded up. Even on a restart,loads up like normally it would.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean. If you drag any view to that "Shared Area" but not to the body but to the header (where the title is supposed to be) the dragged view will occupy completely that "Shared Aread".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

Menu > Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other > Java(default) > Open

Now I can create a new class that shows on the tab next to my working tab.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+{ to toggle it on or Off.

Ctrl+Shift+W to close both of the area.